# Proving that $\int f^2\log \left(\frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)dx \leq \int f^2\left(\log \frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)^2 dx$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

I want to prove the following inequality: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\log \left(\frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right) dx \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\left(\log \frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)^2 dx$$

Note that this inequality remains the same if we multiply $f$ by a scalar $c$. Hence, without loss of generality, we may assume that $\|f\|_2=1$.

Partial solution: By Holder's inequality, and by recalling that $\|f\|_2=1$, we have that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\log \left(\frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right) dx \leq \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\left(\log \frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)^2 dx\right]^{1/2}$$

Hence, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\left(\log \frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)^2 dx\geq 1$, then this implies the inequality that we want. However, I'm unable to prove this inequality if $0\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2\left(\log \frac{|f|}{\|f\|_2}\right)^2 dx<1$.

I am probably missing something quite elementary.

Comment: Indeed, you are missing the limits of integration.

Comment: @Gonçalo- All integrals are to be on the whole real line. I have now added that to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unable to prove the inequality because it is not true in general. Indeed, let's consider the family of normalized functions
$$
f_a(x):=\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2}\quad (a>0). \tag{1}
$$
Since $\|f_a\|_2=1$, the LHS of the inequality is equal to
\begin{align}
F_L(a):&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/2}e^{-ax^2}
\log\left(\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2}\right)dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/2}e^{-ax^2}
\left(\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{2}ax^2\right)dx \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{4}, \tag{2}
\end{align}
whereas its RHS is equal to
\begin{align}
F_R(a):&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/2}e^{-ax^2}
\left(\log\left(\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2}\right)\right)^2dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)^{1/2}e^{-ax^2}
\left(\frac{1}{16}\left(\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)\right)^2
-\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)ax^2
+\frac{1}{4}a^2x^4\right)dx \\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left(\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)\right)^2
-\frac{1}{8}\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)+\frac{3}{16}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Now I'll show that there is a range of values of $a$ such that $F_L(a)>F_R(a)$. Indeed, let $\lambda:=\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{a}{\pi}\right)$; then
\begin{align}
F_L(a)>F_R(a) &\iff \lambda-\frac{1}{4} > \lambda^2-\frac{1}{2}\lambda+\frac{3}{16} \\
&\iff \lambda^2 -\frac{3}{2}\lambda +\frac{7}{16} < 0 \\
&\iff \frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{4}<\lambda<\frac{3+\sqrt{2}}{4} \\
&\iff \pi e^{3-\sqrt{2}}<a< \pi e^{3+\sqrt{2}}. \phantom{\frac{7}{16}} \tag{4}
\end{align}
In particular, $(2)$ and $(3)$ yield
$$
F_L(\pi e^3)-F_R(\pi e^3)=\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\right)-\left(\frac{9}{16}
-\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{16}\right)=\frac{1}{8}>0. \tag{5}
$$

Comment: Nice. I just found the counterexample some minutes ago. I wanted to write a comment. Then I saw your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful example. I did not mention it in the question, but $dx$ is a Gaussian norm, ie the measure that I want to work with is $(2\pi)^{1/2}e^{-x^2/2}dx$. Does this example (or a slightly modified version) still work for this measure? 

I will accept your answer anyway.